# Find the length of Cycle in Linked List in Swift Playground - does it get stuck?

Tags: swift, linked-list, swift-playground

I couldn't see why playground is not showing certain prints() in the findCycleLength function - I'm trying to test if the class functions can produce prints() before the find length of cycle process. Here is what I'm seeing in the console.

```
Hello
am in class of Helloworld
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Here is the code I built -

```
import Foundation
print("Hello")
class Solution {

class func helloWorld() {
    print("am in class of Helloworld")
}

class func findCycleLength(head : Node<Int>?) -> Int {
    var slow = head
    var fast = head
    print("BeforeCycle")
    while fast != nil && slow?.next != nil {
        slow = slow?.next
        fast = fast?.next?.next
        print("During Cycle")
        if slow === fast {
            return calcuateLength(head: slow!)
        }
    }
    
    return 0
}

class func calcuateLength(head : Node<Int>) -> Int {
    var lengthOfCycle = 1
    var current = head.next
    
    while head !== current  {
        current = current!.next
        lengthOfCycle += 1
        print(lengthOfCycle)
    }
    
    return lengthOfCycle
}

}

Solution.helloWorld()

var head = Node(value : 1)
head.next = Node(value: 2)
print(head)
head.next?.next = Node(value: 3)
print(head)
head.next?.next?.next = Node(value: 4)
head.next?.next?.next?.next = Node(value: 5)
head.next?.next?.next?.next?.next = Node(value: 6)
print(head)
head.next?.next?.next?.next?.next?.next = head.next?.next

let cycle = Solution.findCycleLength(head: head)

print("lengthOfCycle: \(lengthOfCycle)")
```

Here's the implementation of Node -

```
import Foundation

public class Node<Element> {
public var value : Element
public var next : Node?
 public weak var previous : Node?

  public init(value : Element) {
  self.value = value
}
}

extension Node: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
    var text = "["
    var node = self
    
    while node != nil {
        text += "\(node.value)"
        
        if let nextNode = node.next {
            text += ", "
            node = nextNode
        }
        else {
            return  text + "]"
        }
    }
    return text + "]"
}
}
```

Revision -

```
extension Node: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        var text = "["
        var node : Node?
        
        node = self
        
        while node != nil {
            text += "\(node!.value)"
            
            if node!.next != nil {
                text += ", "
            }
            else {
                return  text + "]"
            }
            node = node!.next
        }
        return text + "]"
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use a real Xcode projects, so that you can *debug* the program.

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry - updated the code

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that seems I need to do

Comment: Are you sure this implementation of `description` can produce the output? For me, it never terminates.

Comment: Yep. move 'node = nextNode' after the test 'if let nextNode = node', or node will never become nil when the end is reached

Comment: @Moose I edited but it seems the cycle function still is not showing up the console. I'll switch to real xcode project to debug it better, thanks for your help